# Magical Property- Inserir propriedades em outro componente

Tags: delphi

Estou a trabalhar com `flowpanel` no `Delphi` e observei que ele adiciona uma propriedade a mais no `objectInspector`, o `control index`, para os objetos inseridos nele.

Queria saber como é feito isso, se algum dia eu precisasse do recurso, como um componente altera as propriedades de um outro objeto sem ser por herança?

Answer (score 1):

Não consigo te garantir que será o que ele faz mas, para adicionar proriedades e métodos a outros componentes sem herança, basta utilizar `ClassHelpers` (mais informações nesse [link](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Class_and_Record_Helpers_%28Delphi%29))

> **Obs:** Ele adiciona mais proriedades e métodos, mas não podem ser criados Fields.

```
unit StreamHelper;

type
  TStreamHelper = class helper for TStream
  private
    function GetAsByteArray: TByteArray;
    procedure SetAsByteArray(const Value: TByteArray);
  public
    property AsByteArray: Integer read GetAsByteArray write SetAsByteArray;
  end;
```